# if condition cannot catch the null value of my front end username field in javascript and html

Tags: html, if-statement, null

I have a username text field in the login.html file.
I have javascript code as follows

```
loginbtn.addEventListener("click", function() { 
  if(username.value != null) {
    socket.emit("login", {username:username.value});
    $("#name").hide();
    $("#mario-chat").show();
  } else {
    err.innerHTML = document.write("please enter username");
 }
});
```

In the login page i have not entered any name but still my code goes to the if condition and executing the `1$("#name").hide();$("#mario-chat").show();`.
Please tell me why my if condition is executing rather than else part. thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it is because `username.value` is `undefined`. Try changing your if condition to `if(username.value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you console.log(username.value) the result will probably not be null or undefined. That is why != null does not the trick.

username.value might be an empty string so you can add && username.value != '' to the if statement. `if(username.value != null && username.value != ''){}`